# Автоприращивание MySQL не с единицы, а с длинного числа

Tags: php, html, mysql

При создании таблицы MySQL создаю столбец id с авто приращиванием.
 И он начинается с 1. Т.е. 1,2,3,4 и т.д.
Как сделать так, чтобы, например, начинался с 00000001 и продолжал счет? Например:
00000001,00000002, ....00000099,00000100.

Comment: З...з....зачем?

Comment: c 00000001 не прокатит, обрезает до 1

Comment: id - это числовое поле, а числа по правилам математики пишутся без ведущих нулей (а на диске так вообще хранятся в двоичном виде и никаких десятичных нулей у них в принципе быть не может). необходимо при выводе добавлять нули самостоятельно

Comment: Мсье знает толк в приращениях.

Comment: А ничего, что 00000001 и 1 это одно и то же число?

Comment: `1` - это значение. `00000001` - это отображение (одно из кучи возможных) этого значения. MySQL хранит значения, а не их отображение. Нагружайте своими проблемами клиентскую часть.

Answer (score 0):

Никак, и незачем. Если для красоты представления, типа example.com/index.php?id=00000001 или в тексте "ваш id=00000001" вместо "ваш id=1", то конкатенировать (при отображении) и отрезать (при обращении к базе) нужное количество нулей в строке средствами PHP, но в базе оно все равно будет 1, 2, 3,...,n.

Comment: И даже отрезать не придется, (кстати, у Михаила в ответе $input = str_replace("0", "", $input); уберет даже значащие нули, наприме 000103 станет 13, к сожалению, не могу отставлять комментарии с репутацией<50, чтобы поправить), intval($input) вернет integer без первых нулей.

Answer (score 0):

В базе такое не храниться. Для клиентской части подойдет str_pad - вы сможете дописать спереди столько нулей, сколько нужно. А если их надо убрать - str_replace

```
$input = str_pad($input, 8, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

$input = str_replace("0", "", $input);
```

Comment: Localhost, тоже не могу оставить комментарий) тогда можно использовать preg_replace. Шаблон - "/^[0]+/"